# What is the correct way to distribute a SQLServer database with an application?

Tags: sql-server, installation, packaging

Over the years I have seen many approaches to this:

- Packaging a detached database file
- Packaging a backup, which is restored at installation time
- Creating the database from scratch using scripts

In my opinion, the 3rd option, creating a new database from scratch, building the data structure from scripts and populating any static data with a script is the best approach.  Its repeatable, and should always work.

This question could also apply to other dbms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend the third option for the exact reason you suggest.